# Why does the following CSS not work?

Tags: css

I must admit, I expect this to work. In my mind I see my CSS class as selecting, "all child `h2` elements of an element containing `class="jumbotron-features"`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sKAhn/

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron-features h2
{
    color: #797979;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbtron-features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                        <div class="feature-box feature-box-vertical-middle">
                            <h2>Seriously powerful, incredibly intuitive, and designed by real estate experts!</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `jumbtron-features` vs `jumbotron-features`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML should be as so:

```
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-features">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                            <div class="feature-box feature-box-vertical-middle">
                                <h2>Seriously powerful, incredibly intuitive, and designed by real estate experts!</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The reason for this is because you misspelled the class name in the HTML

Answer (score 2):

Your div class is called `jumbtron-features`, not `jumbotron-features`.

Answer (score 2):

Typo error, spelling mistake in class name

Replace this

`.jumbotron-features h2`

with

```
.jumbtron-features h2
```

Working style:

```
<style>
.jumbtron-features h2{
    color: #797979;
    font-style: oblique;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbtron-features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                        <div class="feature-box feature-box-vertical-middle">
                            <h2>Seriously powerful, incredibly intuitive, and designed by real estate experts!</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Class in HTML: `jumbtron-features`

Class in CSS: `jumbotron-features`

'*o*' difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be so mad. Your `div` class is `jumbtron-features` and your CSS class is `jumbOtron-features`. Note, the '*O*'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your code.

CSS has `jumbotron-features`
and HTML has `jumbtron-features`

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/sKAhn/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your class name should be like this:

> ```
> <div class="jumbtron-features">
>     <div class="container">
>         <div class="content">
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
>                     <div class="feature-box feature-box-vertical-middle">
>                         <h2>Seriously powerful, incredibly intuitive, and designed by real estate experts!</h2>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```